# ¿Cómo utilizar más de un operador de forma aleatoria sin que se crucen?

Tags: python, windows, random, math, autonumeric

Recientemente recibí ayuda para generar los paréntesis aleatoriamente sin que se crucen y generen un error. Ahora trato de hacer un operador sin cruzarnos. Lo que quiero hacer es generar aleatoriamente una suma o resta con un paréntesis, pero sin la probabilidad de que se crucen en esa aleatoriedad. Ejemplo.

Quiero evitar esto:

> (4) + -3
>
> --5 - (28)

Y hacer esto:

> (4) + (-3)
>
> -(-5) - (28)

Mi código:

```
import random

archivo=open('numerosconparentesis.txt', 'w')
options_operators=[('+', '-'),('-','')]
options_general=[('-',''),('','-'),('-','-'),('','')]
parenthesis_operators=[('(',')','',''),('','','(',')'),('','','',''),('(',')','(',')')]
up=0
result=[]

insert=int(input('Ingresa la cantidad de números a generar: '))
for i in range(insert):
    up+=1
    n1=random.randint(1, 100)
    n2=random.randint(1, 100)
    options,options1=random.choice(options_operators)
    ops,ops1=random.choice(options_general)
    opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4=random.choice(parenthesis_operators)
    result.append(eval(str(ops)+str(opt1)+str(ops1)+str(n1)+str(opt2)+str(options)+str(opt3)+str(ops)+str(n2)+str(opt4)))
    archivo.write(f'{up}.- {ops}{opt1}{ops1}{n1}{opt2} {options} {opt3}{options1}{n2}{opt4} =\n\n')
    

archivo.write('---------------------\n')
up=0
for i in range(insert):
    up+=1
    archivo.write(f'{result[i]}\n\n')
archivo.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres crear sumas aletorias donde uno de los sumandos esté entre paréntesis.

Hay que señalar que en python no da error por añadir varios signos de suma y resta seguidos (eg `+++--++ -+1 == -1`). Si queremos paréntesis es más por un tema estético que otra cosa.

Si analizamos, los sumandos con paréntesis tienen la siguiente casuística:

```py
-(-5) + 8
-(-5) - 8
 3 + (-1)
-3 + (-1)
 3 - (-1)
-3 - (-1)
```

Que podemos representar con los siguientes formatos:

```py
fmts = (
    "-(-{}) + {}",
    "-(-{}) - {}",
    "{} + (-{})",
    "-{} + (-{})",
    "{} - (-{})",
    "-{} - (-{})"
)
```

Con esto podemos armar el código para generar expresiones aleatorias:

```py
from random import randint, choice

fmts = (
    "-(-{}) + {}",
    "-(-{}) - {}",
    "{} + (-{})",
    "-{} + (-{})",
    "{} - (-{})",
    "-{} - (-{})"
)

for i in range(20):
    x,y = randint(1,99), randint(1,99)
    expr = choice(fmts).format(x,y)
    print(f"{expr} = {eval(expr)}")
```

Resultado:

```
68 - (-82) = 150
32 - (-43) = 75
-76 - (-3) = -73
-50 - (-92) = 42
-45 + (-79) = -124
-(-96) - 59 = 37
61 - (-32) = 93
3 - (-4) = 7
-71 - (-90) = 19
19 - (-54) = 73
-(-80) + 75 = 155
25 + (-10) = 15
72 + (-64) = 8
76 - (-64) = 140
30 - (-43) = 73
-(-88) + 32 = 120
-(-60) + 39 = 99
-36 - (-10) = -26
84 - (-51) = 135
-(-41) + 48 = 89
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias, se me había cruzado por la cabeza crear un código con permutaciones para generar las posibilidades de los paréntesis con los operadores para que me arrojara más o menos los formatos que me comentas, de momento eso resuelve mi duda. Saludos amigo!

Comment: Acuérdate de marcarlo si te ha servido como solución.

Answer (score 2):

Una solución es ponerle "()" a cada número antes de armar la operación.

Para eso defino una simple función que genera un valor aleatorio entre -100 y 100, presentado en formato texto y paréntesis. Con esto me evito tener que lidiar con los "-" unitarios por separado.

```
def gen_operando():
    n = random.randint(-100, 100)
    return f"({n})"
```

La función `gen_suma` retorna una cadena conteniendo una suma o resta de enteros:

```
def gen_suma():
    n1 = gen_operando()
    n2 = gen_operando()
    op = '+' if random.randint(1, 2) == 1 else '-'
    return n1 + op + n2
```

Esta función la puedo probar con:

```
for i in range(10):
    operacion = gen_suma()
    print(operacion, eval(operacion))
```

En cada iteración se genera una nueva operación, la que se imprime y se pasa a `eval`, que la evaluara numericamente.

```
(-74)-(-58) -16
(58)+(1) 59
(-42)-(-52) 10
(20)+(-93) -73
(-96)-(-24) -72
(-74)-(-85) 11
(7)+(15) 22
(-63)+(6) -57
(12)-(2) 10
(-87)+(80) -7
```

Puedes usar esto como base para generar el archivo deseado.

Comment: Me parece muy optimizado el código lo acabo de probar, solo que el problema comienza desde el inicio al definir los paréntesis sin hacerlos aleatorios. Me explico, al poner los paréntesis, siempre que se ejecute el código me va a arrojar los números con paréntesis y yo no quiero eso, quiero que los paréntesis sean random.  El segundo problema viene que solo admite los dos operadores (suma y resta) dentro del primer paréntesis, si por ejemplo, un negativo multiplica a otro negativo "- (-3)" y el primer paréntesis no podrá aplicar la ley de signos de negativos, el segundo paréntesis sí.

Comment: El código cumple perfectamente con las operaciones básicas de suma, resta y leyes de signos, pero trato de hacer por mera estética añadir los signos. Pero muchas gracias por la ayuda, hoy aprendí a optimizar el código de manera más sencilla. Saludos!